# Controlling Servo Motor with Potentiometer

Tags: arm, embedded, mbed

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Servo.h"

Servo myservo(D6);
AnalogOut MyPot(A0);


int main() {
    float PotReading;
    PotReading = MyPot.read();

    while(1) {
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            myservo = i/100.0;
            wait(0.01);
        }

        }
    }
```

I just started learning how to code for arm embedded and I am stuck in trying to figure out how to control the servo motor a 10k potentiometer. I have a Nucleo L496ZG board and a Tower Pro Micro Servo 9G. I connected the D6 to the PWM of the servo and connected the potentiometer signal to A0. Then connected them to ground and to 5V. I'm just having issue with the coding and if anyone can suggest/help out. Appreciate it.

Comment: What is the issue that you are having?

Comment: I trying to control the servo with the pwm

Comment: That issue do you have with controlling the servo with pwm? Be specific.

Comment: I'm using a potentiometer

Comment: First of all you need to establish a sensible unit. The ADC reads voltage in the form of raw numbers. The PWM uses timer ticks. In my experience, PWM timer ticks is often a good unit to use program-wide. So start by converting the ADC read to a duty cycle. Should be plain linear equations.

Comment: And, what is your question? What do you expect? What do you get?